# AJAX Counter and Update Panel help needed !

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax

I am making a clone of quibids.com in asp.net. This site is in PHP. Can anyone check it and tell me which technology / language they are using behind those so many running counters at the same time ? Is that server side counter or client side counter ? I have tried ajax counter and ajax update panel in asp.net but it is taking so much time to load all counters and to run those counters. You can see my created website at : www.vif-tech.com/BidsOnline

Can anyone suggest me any good server side counter than ajax counter which can run fast or if I use a simple javascript counter, how can I bind it with database ?

Awaiting your help guys .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using fiddler, I can tell they are making ajax calls in php every 1 second to get the latest bid info for all the bids. They are pretty small calls..about 200 bytes each, so it's fast.

The ajax calls on your page are about 70kb every 1 second, making it very slow & and heavy on your server when you have a dozen users at once.

Download fiddler and run it while using your page. Then try to get that request size down.

Comment: Large Update Panels increase the size of your requests because everything in the panel has to be rendered on every request.

You can use webservice calls via PageMethods to speed up your site. Use them to only retrieve the data that you want to update.
http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: Fiddler is a Web Debugger software. How can I use that to size down my page's request ?

Comment: Fiddler is used to see what your page & ajax request size is. 
For a page like yours that updates every second, you would have to switch away from using the <ASP:UpdatePanel> which is made for convenience and not high performance. Here's another example of using PageMethods & Ajax with jQuery. http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
It can make your site a lot faster.

Comment: What is the alternate of Ajax Counter ? Because I am using Ajax Counter and it is data bound, Can I data bound jQuery or any other Jscript counter ?